# How do i use a ListView without getting errors?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to get a listview working inside a column. I am getting a billion errors. I tried using `Expanded()`, but it seems not to be giving any results

Here is the code:

```
Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
              color: const Color(0xFF242323),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(27, 23, 27, 12),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: const [
                              GradientText(
                                "Skol",
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Color(0xFFf5ab16),
                                    Color(0xFFe8a215),
                                    Color(0xFFcf9013),
                                  ],
                                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                ),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 44,
                                  fontFamily: "Informal",
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              // Skol title

                              CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFb77f11),
                                radius: 24,
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage:
                                      AssetImage("assets/images/user.png"),
                                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFfedc76),
                                  radius: 22,
                                ),
                                // Avatar
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          // navbar top area
                        ),
                        // Skol Title and User Button
                        ListView()
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ))),
    );
```

When I look it up, they are saying to use `shrinkwrap` or `sizedbox`.

Can someone explain to me what is the reason behind this error?

Comment: Try to wrap your ListView with `Expanded` widget

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your ListView with Expanded widget.

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Container(
      color: const Color(0xFF242323),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(27, 23, 27, 12),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: const [],
                  ),
                  // navbar top area
                ),
                // Skol Title and User Button
                Expanded(child: ListView())
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```